# Node.js/socket.io design confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, real-time

I am wondering if I am doing things in the wright way

There is a notification system in my system which I have implemented in the following way.

**Server:**

```
 socket.on('do_activity',function(packet){
 io.emit("notification_found_"+packet.receiver_id,packet);
});
```

**Client:**

```
socket.on("notification_found_10",function(){
 //do some action
});
```

**Note:** The server notifies a user regarding some activity found by user. The packet variable contains the target user id, (10 in my case).

The server listens to the `do_activity` event listener and emits `notification_found`  event to the client

**Questions:**

- 1) The server propagates the "`notification_found_<user i>`" event for
  each user with the suffixed ID of the user. Is this the right way to
  implement a notification system?
- 2) Since any malicious user from the browser can emit the do_activity
  event, how to secure it?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly is it being implemented? What information is known by one client about the other when initiating the action? If there's some arbitrary information you can use to encode your receiver_id it's possible to make this more secure. Like username, or something else that's harder to guess than a number. And if it's implemented on a secure portion of the site that requires privileges to access that cuts down the concern as well. A little more information would be helpful.

Comment: I encode the user id. But I am asking is this the correct way to propagate an event to a specific user?

Comment: I see, I was looking at point #2 you asked above, "how to secure it?" Again, I think there's too little information to answer the question well. Is your receiver_id the socket.id?

Comment: no it is a numeric user id. My client is basically developed in PHP

Comment: It does not really make sense to send a message that is for only one user to all your users and then have the users filter through them.  You should send the message to only the user that it is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a commenter posted above, it does not make sense to send notifications to all users if they are intended to a subgroup/individual only.

I'd suggest you take a look at rooms and namespaces to segregate the distribution of such notifications. Check this from the [documentation](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) itself.